# Sql Case When query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

i've found "CASE WHEN" statement very useful for my query.
But this is my query (only select):

```
SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
        CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
        CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS 'T/R', 
        CASE 'T/R' WHEN 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente,
```

the problem is on third Case statement, because don't evaluate previous 'T/R' query (for all record it return 'CONTACTORIGIN.address'.
it is possible to do this? or i'm in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to define the `T/R` alias;

```
SELECT  *
,       CASE 'T/R' WHEN 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address 
            END AS Utente
FROM    (
        SELECT  CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO
        ,       CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' 
                    END AS 'T/R'
        FROM    dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to repeat the test:

```
SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
        CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
        CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS 'T/R', 
        CASE CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE NOT IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente,
```

Or you can make a subquery :

```
SELECT PROTOCOLLO, ESITO, [T/R],
    CASE WHEN [T/R] = 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente
FROM
(SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
        CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
        CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS [T/R], 
) s
```

Comment: Also might consider using subselects or views.

Comment: Was just editing my answer adding the subquery, good point :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat your case statements you have two options, the first is to move one of them to a subquery, i.e.

```
SELECT  PROTOCOLLO,
        ESITO,
        [T/R],
        CASE [T/R] WHEN 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente
FROM    (   SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
                    CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
                    CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS 'T/R'
            FROM    ....
        ) SubQuery
```

Or you could move your CASE Statement inside a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
        CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
        'T/R', 
        CASE [T/R] WHEN 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente
FROM    ...
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS 'T/R'
        ) tx
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're computing a value for a column in the `SELECT` clause, you're not allowed to access any other computed value being computed in the same `SELECT` clause - because (per SQL standard) the columns are being computed in parallel (they may not be, but it's assumed that some implementations *will* do this), so the computed values aren't yet available.

You can put "earlier" calculations in a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE [T/R] WHEN 'TX' THEN CONTACTORIGIN.address ELSE CONTACTDESTINATION.address END AS Utente
FROM (
    SELECT  dbo.ARCHIVE.SYSTEM_KEY AS PROTOCOLLO, 
        CASE dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.ERR_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'KO' END AS ESITO, 
        CASE WHEN dbo.ARCHIVEDEST.XMODE IN ('R', 'K', 'H') THEN 'RX' ELSE 'TX' END AS [T/R], 

    ...
) t
```